# Moveit: Link collides with itself

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, simulation, moveit, gripper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Upon spawning the robotiq gripper palm found here https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq/blob/groovy-devel/robotiq_s_model_visualization/cfg/s-model_articulated_macro.xacro

Even after removing the fingers, the palm has a red collision with itself (Rviz says so, and when used with a full arm model it refuses to plan in MoveIt!)

Could it be because of this stl file? Do visual tags collide with collision tags? Any insight would be appreciated here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199759/moveit:-link-collides-with-itself/) by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 644 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no idea why, but this was fixed by re-downloading the URDF model from the repo. This was one of the stranger bugs..

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0